# How to get the array of objects based on condition check using javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, object

I have array of objects and two param values

I would like to know to how to update value `val` by `paramVal`

when `paramId` is same  as `id` in list and

if its is same then increment the value until no value being same and return the list.

```js
var list = [
  { id: 10, val: null, color: 'red' },
  { id: 23, val: 1, color: 'blue' },
  { id: 13, val: 3, color: 'yellow' },
  { id: 44, val: 4, color: 'black' },
  { id: 55, val: 2, color: 'indigo' },
];

var paramId = 44;
var paramValue = 3;

//Tried
let result = [];
for (const item of list) {
  if (item.val === paramValue && item.id !== paramId) {
    item.val = item.val ?? item.val + 1;
    result.push(item);
  }
}
console.log(result);
```

Expected Output

```
// when set var paramId = 44, var paramValue = 3

[
  {id:23, val: 1, color: "blue"},
  {id:55, val: 2, color: "indigo"}
  {id:13, val: 4, color: "yellow"},
  {id:44, val: 3, color: "black"},
  {id:10, val: null, color: "red"}
]
```

```
// when set paramId= 13, paramValue = 2 and list returns

[
  { id: 23, val: 1, color: 'blue' },
  { id: 13, val: 2, color: 'yellow' },
  { id: 55, val: 3, color: 'indigo' },
  { id: 44, val: 4, color: 'black' },
  { id: 10, val: null, color: 'red' },
]
```

Comment: @Yogi thanks for reply, dont want to use filter since i need to update the value

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your issue is that you only `.push()` to your new array when the condition matches, so your final array will be smaller than your initial one.

Also, in your example, `item.val = ...` will modify the item in the *original* array *and* the new array, which could cause bugs if someone else is using the `list` variable. Instead, you could treat `list` as "immutable," so instead of modifying it in place, you make a copy of each element.

If you want to transform every element of an array, [`.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) is very helpful, which lets you run a function on every item on the list, and transform each item however you want.

The following example takes advantage of the "fat arrow" function syntax using `=>`, where the body of the function doesn't need to have wrapping curly braces `{` `}`, and doesn't need a return statement if it's all one line. It also returns an object in place, using the special `=> ({ ... })` syntax of fat arrow functions. And it copies the original object using the `...` "object spread" operator.

```js
const list = [
  { id: 10, val: null, color: 'red' },
  { id: 23, val: 1, color: 'blue' },
  { id: 13, val: 3, color: 'yellow' },
  { id: 44, val: 4, color: 'black' },
  { id: 55, val: 2, color: 'indigo' },
];
const updateList = (ignoreId, matchValue) =>
  list.map((item) => ({
    ...item,
    val:
      item.id !== ignoreId && item.val === matchValue
        ? (item.val || 0) + 1
        : item.val,
  }));

console.log(updateList(44, 3));
```

Comment: thanks for reply, code not working when passing `updateList(13, 2)` returns list but { id: 55, val: 2, color: 'indigo' }, should increment the value but still shows same

Comment: Logic: if paramId and paramVal matches with item.val, item.id update the value in the list. if paramId and item.id is same  and item.val < list.length (exclude without null) then increment that object item.val or item.val.

Comment: Your comment is incorrect. `updateList(13, 2)` returns the indigo entry to `{id: 55, val: 3, color: 'indigo'}`. For your second comment, it sounds like you're changing the criteria to be different than your original question, and your requirements are not clear. Please edit your question to make the criteria clear, or it may be closed. Your question is already hard to follow, please review [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to help get better and faster answers in the future.